# Python Tkinter or ttk, Send text to other toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am using a separate top level window during development of my Python ttk code, and would like to send messages from root to debug top level window.

Here is some pseudo code

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from MyFunctions import *    # some code I wrote (see below)
root = Tk()
SetupMyFunct(root)           # see below
de_bug = Toplevel(root)
dbug_frame = Frame(de_bug).grid()
debug_string1 = StringVar()
debug1_window = ttk.Label(dbug_frame, textvariable = debug_string1).grid()
root.mainloop()
```

In my MyFunctions.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
def SetupMyFunct(root):
    f = ttk.Frame(root).grid()
    w = Frame(f).grid()
```

At this point I would like to send some text to be automatically updated in the de_bug window, but I really have no idea where to go from here.

Help Please?
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining the geometry management method prevents you from retaining a reference to those widgets, as those methods return `None` to be stored in those variables. Stop doing that. This will allow you to do things like work with references to your widgets. Specifically, you will be able to specify `dbug_frame` as the parent object for the `debug1_window` widget.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from MyFunctions import *
root = Tk()
f,w = SetupMyFunct(root)
de_bug = Toplevel(root)
dbug_frame = Frame(de_bug)
dbug_frame.grid()
debug_string1 = StringVar()
debug1_window = ttk.Label(dbug_frame, textvariable=debug_string1)
debug1_window.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
def SetupMyFunct(root):
    f = ttk.Frame(root)
    f.grid()
    w = Frame(f)
    w.grid()
    return f,w
```